# How to wait till text value is fully loaded in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, cookies, automation, webdriverwait

I tried the following code in Selenium to get the row values.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www2.asx.com.au/");

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    try {

        WebElement cookies = driver.findElementByXPath("//button[text()='Accept All Cookies']");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(cookies)).click();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("cookies pop up not found");
    }

    WebElement el = driver
            .findElementByXPath("//*[@class='markit-home-top-five aem-GridColumn aem-GridColumn--default--12']");

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(el));

    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", el);
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElementsByXPath("//caption[text()='Gains']//ancestor::table//tr");

    for (int i = 1; i <= elements.size(); i++) {

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        System.out.println(driver.findElementByXPath(
                "//caption[text()='Gains']//ancestor::table//tr[" + i + "]//span[@class='value-with-arrow']")
                .getText());
    }

}
```

I faced two issues:

1. The 'Allow all cookies' button is not getting clicked and the pop up remains there. 'cookies pop up not found' is getting printed in the output.
2. The value of the tables are not getting printed without sleep. in the below output ,it is shown that the first text value is printed as -- as the value was still loading. How to provide till the value is fully loaded.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.id("element_id"), "The Text"));
```

use webdriver wait , you can use expected condition texttobepresent or element to be present

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#textToBePresentInElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By,java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Any idea why the same is not working for the cookies pop up?